# Stretch last div element to fill the remaing space css flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
        .main {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    height: 100vh;
    /* flex-direction: column; */
}

.header{
    background-color: hotpink;
}
.filter{
    background-color: indianred;
}
.sort{
    background-color: lavender;
}

.jobs{
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
   
}

.joblist{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}



body,html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
  
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="header">
            <span>Header</span>
        </div>
        <div class="filter">
            <h1>Filter</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="sort">
            <h1>Sort</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="jobs">
            <div class="joblist">
                <div class="items">
                    <div class="item">1</div>
                    <div class="item">2</div>
                    <div class="item">3</div>
                    <div class="item">4</div>
                    <div class="item">5</div>
                    <div class="item">6</div>

                </div>
                <div class="pagination">
                    <h1>Pagination</h1>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="jobview">
                content
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I have put  `height: 100vh` to paint the full viewport with green color. header, filter, sort should take the relevant space they needed. The rest of the space should occupy by the jobs section. ideally, the jobs section should scroll all the way to the bottom. I tried  `flex-grow: 1` and in some places, it says `flex-grow works only for the main-axis so I tried to` flex-direction: column` to make the main-axis. But still no results.

How could I achieve this with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add `display: flex;` and uncomment the `flex-direction: column;` to get the effect you need. The `flex-grow: 1;` or `flex: 1;` for short did not take effect because the parent itself wasn't a `flexbox`.

```css
.main {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.header {
  background-color: hotpink;
}

.filter {
  background-color: indianred;
}

.sort {
  background-color: lavender;
}

.jobs {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.joblist {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.footer {
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
}

body,
html, * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      <span>Header</span>
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
      <h1>Filter</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="sort">
      <h1>Sort</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="jobs">
      <div class="joblist">
        <div class="items">
          <div class="item">1</div>
          <div class="item">2</div>
          <div class="item">3</div>
          <div class="item">4</div>
          <div class="item">5</div>
          <div class="item">6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pagination">
          <h1>Pagination</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jobview">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    height: 100vh;
    /* flex-direction: column; */
}

.header{
    background-color: hotpink;
}
.filter{
    background-color: indianred;
}
.sort{
    background-color: lavender;
}

.jobs{
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height:100%;
   
}

.joblist{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}



body,html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
  
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="header">
            <span>Header</span>
        </div>
        <div class="filter">
            <h1>Filter</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="sort">
            <h1>Sort</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="jobs">
            <div class="joblist">
                <div class="items">
                    <div class="item">1</div>
                    <div class="item">2</div>
                    <div class="item">3</div>
                    <div class="item">4</div>
                    <div class="item">5</div>
                    <div class="item">6</div>

                </div>
                <div class="pagination">
                    <h1>Pagination</h1>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="jobview">
                content
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding height:100% to jobs class has one issue. Then jobs class itself take 100vh height. So need to scroll to see the  full page

Answer (score 0):

I suggest giving each of the divs a height so that each has its own space like so. You can use vh instead of % also

```
.header{
    background-color: hotpink;
    height: 10%;
}
.filter{
    background-color: indianred;
    height: 15%;
}
.sort{
    background-color: lavender;
    height: 15%;
}

.jobs{
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 60%;
```

Comment: header, filter, sort are dynamically rendering. Sometimes there may not a filter section at all. Better if I assign all remaining space to jobs class

Comment: In such case go for height: 100% for jobs, but for a more organized structure you can also use calc() function. Something like height: calc(100vh - sum of rest of the divs)